# spring cloud sleuth otel - tracing data not visible to jaeger dashboard

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth, jaeger, open-telemetry

I have followed multiple blogs to set-up working demo of Spring cloud Sleuth with OTEL.
App ran successfully, trace and spanId are getting generated but service is not getting registered with local jaeger (dockerized) and hence not able to see any trace data.

Kindly review the configuration and help me.

Under

```
Dependency management
spring-boot-starter-parent=2.6.6
spring-cloud-dependencies:2021.0.1
spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-dependencies:1.1.0-M4
```

dependencies

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Brave (the default) -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-brave</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-trace</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>1.42.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

App config(yml)

```
spring:
  application:
    name: api-service
  sleuth:
    otel:
      exporter:
        otlp:
          endpoint: http://collector:6831
```

Docker compose

```
version: "3.5"

services:

  api-service:
    build: api-service/
    image: api-service:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  collector:
    image: jaegertracing/opentelemetry-all-in-one
    ports:
      - 5775:5775/udp
      - 6831:6831/udp
      - 6832:6832/udp
      - 5778:5778
      - 16686:16686
      - 14268:14268
      - 14250:14250
      - 9411:9411
```

I made few API calls to api-service but not able to see any trace data and service name on jaeger dashboard (http://localhost:16686).

[image]

Comment: `jaegertracing/opentelemetry-all-in-one` is discontinued image. I would recommend to use `jaegertracing/all-in-one` (I'm not saying that will solve the problem!)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.33/getting-started/#all-in-one

6831 port accepts `jaeger.thrift` over compact thrift protocol, but your exporter is sending OTLP GRPC protocol => you are mixing protocols.

I believe `55680` port was used for OTLP protocol, but `jaegertracing/opentelemetry-all-in-one` is discontinued image, so it is hard to find doc for that.

I would use `jaegertracing/all-in-one` image and jaeger exporter (not otlp).

Comment: I have changed to jaegertracing/all-in-one. I don't see OTLP protocol (grpc) on the document. Which port/protocol I should use?

Comment: On that page there are only UDP protocol at agent component side. It doesn't have gRPC  mentioned.